If $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ then can we say that $\mu(\operatorname{supp}(f)-\{f\ne 0\})=0$?
If $f\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ then can we say that $\mu(\operatorname{supp}(f)-\{f\ne 0\})=0$? Assume $\Omega\subset \mathbb R$ and $\mu$ lebesuge measure.
Showing one of the below is fine:

$\mu(\{f=0\}\cap\operatorname{supp}(f))=0$.
$\mu(f\ne 0)=\mu(\overline{f\ne 0})$.
$\mu(\operatorname{supp}(f)-\{f\ne 0\})=0$.

I tried for $f\in C^1$ first but get no clue. Please help me with that.

No. Take $F=$ a fat Cantor set in $\Omega=[0,1]$. Since $F$ is closed one can find a smooth compactly supported function $f$ such that $f=0$ on $F$. Now assuming by support you mean the closure of the set where $f\neq 0$, we have $\text{supp}(f) = \overline{F^c} = [0,1]$ since $F$ is nowhere dense. But $\text{supp}(f) \setminus \{f\neq 0\} = F$ which has positive Lebesgue measure.

I did think about this function but I am not sure whether this is weakly differentiable or not? does it lie in $W^{1,p}$ for some $p\ge 1$.

Yes, it's smooth, so all derivatives exist in the classical sense.
